# Facebook SDK method presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession is not sending any request to my friends

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send a comment using Facebook iOS SDK to my FB friends.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[_usersFB valueForKey:@"selectValue"] componentsJoinedByString:@","], @"to",
                                                 nil];


[FBWebDialogs
                      presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                      message:@"Test Comment"
                      title:nil
                      parameters:params
                      handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                              NSLog(@"Error sending request.");

                          } else {
                              if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                  // User clicked the "x" icon
                                  NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                              } else {
                                  // Handle the send request callback
                              }
                          }
                      }];
```

I'm using FB SDK v3.5.3.

I see all the friends in the FBDialog but when I tap on the send button the callback returns no error assuming it worked but my selected friends hasn't received anything.

FYI - My FB app is not in sandbox mode.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but I couldn't figure out why. It used to work for a while and then when I switched to a different Facebook app id, it stopped working. I checked that I set everything up correctly in the info.plist but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open the facebook page or app in an iPhone device when you check if it worked.

The notifications will not appear on facebook on on desktop browsers, only on iPhones.

I hope it helps.